# Adding Quests to my game

Tags: php, javascript

I've finally decided to add quests to my game. I'd like the quests to be individual to each other. Maybe later one, one having another quest completed before that one is accessed. Anyway.

How do I go about this? I've thought about it a ton. I'm a PHP/Javascript/Mysqli guy.

You talk to a NPC, if you pick the right "answers" they will start the quest. You do the tasks, you might have to talk to other NPCs. It all depends. How do i store the conversations and show them?

Thanks.

***EDIT***

This is what I've "Done".

```
var people = [];
people[1]=['name'=>'Joe'];
people[1]['questions'][1] = 'Why, hello there';
people[1]['questions'][1]['send'] = 1;
people[1]['questions'][2] = 'My name is Joe, You seem to be new around here';
people[1]['questions'][2]['send'] = 2;
people[1]['questions'][3] = 'Why certainly! How about I send you on a quest to help you.  It will get you aquainted with Corgate';
people[1]['questions'][3]['send'] = makequest(1);
people[1]['answers'][1] = array('Hello, who are you?');
people[1]['answers'][1]['send'] = 2;
people[1]['answers'][2] = array("I'm not new! Good bye!",'Yes I am, Can you help me?');
people[1]['answers'][2]['send'][1] = 3;
people[1]['answers'][2]['send'][2] = endthis();
```

Very sloppy. yes. Basically, It starts with the question. Then "sends" to the answer with that Id. Then, based one the array of answers chosen, it then sends that to the corresponding question.

Comment: your first quest would be to incorporate your attempt so far. 

Reward: answers

Comment: This is a pretty vague question but I think you'd be served well by looking around on the gamedev stack exchange site http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ to get some ideas of how other people may have implemented quests in their games

Comment: Hint: Conversation trees are trees.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Explain please?

Comment: A conversation tree is a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd basically do it with tables in your DB.

If the conversations are all linear, you could do searches for next NPC response with

```
SELECT NPC.response WHERE NPC.previous = ? AND NPC.player_response = ?
```

where the ? are what the NPC said last, and how the player responded.

If the player chooses the "wrong" response, nothing will match the query and the NPC will remain silent.

Comment: So I'd have to put in each and every answer for each question?

Comment: Yes; you'd have to put every possible answer either in your array structure or in the DB.

Comment: Okay. I'll see how that goes :)

Comment: I'd spend some time designing the tables and how you'll access them before you start writing code.